# How can you implement Azure Function slots without downtime?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager, azure-cli

I'm attempting to implement a Function slot and prevent any downtime during deployment. I can get this working but only if I never change any application settings. When an application setting is changed it causes a restart.

One pattern I've seen recommended for this is to not declare application settings in ARM for production slot. This seems to make sense and, surprisingly, works with Complete mode.

However, when deploying the Function for the first time to a clean environment without production app settings defined this will always fail on slot swap. Many of the Azure Functions are set in app settings. For example the Functions version, app insights key, storage, etc. If you omit these on a clean deploy and attempt to swap it will never deploy.

So I'm in a position where I need to omit application settings to get the deployment model to work but the application settings include mandatory settings for the infrastructure. I've tried switching to using az cli for the function app creation. I've had limited success but I also have ARM resources that depend on the function existing such as role assignments and alerts. I'd rather not go down a hybrid model if I can help it and I'd also like to keep the declarative target state that's provided with ARM's complete mode.

Am I missing an option here to get zero downtime, plus successful first deploy and allow updating of Function settings? Looks like it's not possible.

Comment: Are you adding the appsettings to the slot?

Comment: Yea, I apply the appsettings to both production and staging through ARM. I seem to be able to omit them on subsequent deploys but a clean slate deploy with no app settings won't work.

Comment: Why are you adding them to production? My understanding of this is that you should add these to the slot (only), "warm it" then swap them. Maybe try that?

Comment: If you don't add them to production the first time you deploy the Function it won't work. Reason for this is no version is supplied so defaults to V1 and no settings supplied around storage account etc. It would work the next time if you deleted the appsettings, but it's a chicken and egg situation and pretty flaky. You couldn't then deploy to a new environment from scratch.

Comment: Well if this is the first time your deploying why is downtime an issue? I'm really not following

Comment: Scenario is: no prod setting specified but specified in staging slot - this will never work to a clean slate environment. No number of retries will fix it.You always need to specify production appsettings to get a function into an environment for the first time. So if I wanted to deploy to a new environment this wouldn't be possible without changing the code first.

If the app already exists in an environment, you are able to remove appsettings and have it work.